# I am sending user credentials in header part using POST method

Tags: java, performance, http-headers, http-post

I know it is very basic question but I need a solid answer to clear my thoughts on it.

I am sending user credentials, key etc in header part in POST method,
Is it a good way? if not then why?

Comment: Doing this over plain HTTP is a terrible idea. With HTTPS it's much better. However, your application might be fooled to leak the credentials and then you're toasted. I guess, combining headers with [HttpOnly cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23035655/581205) is best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bad way of doing things like these since **if somebody could intercept your request - they would get your credentials easily**. Better to avoid or at least encrypt this kind of requests.

One of the most popular solutions nowadays is to use **OAuth 2.0 (or even better - OpenID Connect)**. They will bring some complexity to your system but the cool thing about it is that **your application doesn't have to deal with passwords at all**. Everything is delegated to Authority Server. And there are a lot of the authorization servers ready to use, for instance [Keycloak](http://www.keycloak.org/) (we have been using it and it and it was really good experience for us)